# Limits as $x$ approaches one from the left

Tags: limits

How do I find $$\lim_{x \to 1^-} -\frac{1}{x-1}$$  Can someone please show me how to work it out algebraically?

Comment: Do you mean $\frac{-1}{x-1}$ or $-\frac1x-1$?

Comment: @HenningMakholm exactly how it is there

Comment: You don't do this algebraically:  think about what this function does as you use values of  $ \ x \ $ slightly smaller than 1 , say, 0.9, then insert values gradually closer to 1, say, 0.99, 0.999, ... (Notice that something different happens if you use values slightly _larger_ than 1, say, 1.1, 1.01, 1.001, etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $x$ is "to the left of" $1$, i.e. less than $1$, $x-1$ is negative, so $-1/(x-1)$ is positive.  Since the denominator is approaching $0$ as the numerator remains fixed, what happens is what always happens in that situation.  Picture the denominator being a tiny number --- say $0.0000000000001$.  You're dividing the numerator by it.  How many times would it go into the numerator?  What kind of number do you get?

Comment: Im barely starting my calculus class and im finding it difficult

Comment: The way I think of it is "-" reminds me of small numbers so "1-" means smaller than one. And "+" reminds me of large numbers, so "1+" means larger than 1. You'll get used to it, and then it'll be easy. @user268533